# reference object name with another object value

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
args.e = 'asset' 

const entitySettings = {
  asset: {
    version: "1-0-0"
  }
}
```

I want to reference this in another object e.g.

```
entitySettings.args[e].version
```

But I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'e' of undefined`

`args.e` definitely has a value. How can I use this within the property reference to eventually translate to `entitySettings.asset.version` and ultimately to `1-0-0` ?

Comment: `const args.e = 'asset' ` is invalid syntax...

Comment: `args.e` might be defined but `args` is not part of `entitySettings`

Comment: Use `entitySettings[args.e]`

Comment: you're the man Jack! got it.... thanks